# (React Native) Expo BarCodeScanner does not scan in production

Tags: android, react-native, apk, barcode

Everything works perfectly during testing, but as soon as I publish to expo or install the apk, the barcode scanner won't scan at all. It will request permissions to use the camera and the camera will turn on, but it does nothing when I try to scan a upc label or a qr code. Any help would be greatly appriciated.

I'm using the code from the example here: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/bar-code-scanner/

Answer (score 0):

Use expo-camera instead, BarCodeScanner has an bug in expo ver 43